# Future<String> as text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, future, languagetool

I don't have much experience with flutter.

I would like to use the language_tool library for Dart and Flutter (https://pub.dev/packages/language_tool)

I created this script in dart which prints to the console, the .message of the first item in the list.

```
void tool(String text) async {
  var tool = LanguageTool();
  var result = tool.check(text);

  List correction = await result;
  print(correction[0].message);
}

void main() {
  tool('Henlo i am Gabriele');
}
```

After, I would like: correction [0] .message, to appear as text in my flutter app, but I don't know how I can do it as the tool() function has to return a Future .

How can I do?

```
class mainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Chat(),
    );
  }
}

class Chat extends StatefulWidget {
  const Chat({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ChatState createState() => _ChatState();
}

class _ChatState extends State<Chat> {
  String text = 'Henlo i am Gabriele';

  Future<String> tool(String text) async {
    var tool = LanguageTool();

    var result = tool.check(text);

    List correction = await result;

    //print(correction[0].message);
    return correction[0].message;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Text(text),
            //Text(tool(text)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope someone can help me,
Thank you.

Comment: Look into `FutureBuilder`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter Future <String > cant be assigned to parameter type string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61702458/flutter-future-string-cant-be-assigned-to-parameter-type-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tool()` is a `Future` method. Try using `FutureBuilder`.

```dart
FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: tool(text),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData &&
        snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
      return Text(snapshot.data!);
    }

    return CircularProgressIndicator();
  },
)
```

Check more about [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and [When should I use a FutureBuilder?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51983011/10157127)

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because you are not using a FutureBuilder. Try using a FutureBuilder. You can solve it by wrapping your widget in a FutureBuilder.

check this post [Flutter Future <String > cant be assigned to parameter type string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61702458/flutter-future-string-cant-be-assigned-to-parameter-type-string)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a FutureBuilder class:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child: Column(
        children: [
          Text(text),
          FutureBuilder<String>(
            future: _calculation,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) =>
              Text(tool(snapshot.data)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```